# Items added to List (AddRange) are changed when the table added to AddRange is changed

Tags: c#, list, foreach, reference

I would expect this to happen if I initiating my temp list outside the loop, but I am not so do not understand why I am getting the result I am. My code is essentially:

```
foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
{
    List<IItemData> tempTable = new List<IItemData>();
    tempTable = CreateCopyOfTemplate(item, new List<IItemData>(), tableTemplate, itemDataList, item.Id, tableSortOrder);

    foreach (IItemData itemData in tempTable)
    {
        if (itemData.Content.StartsWith("cdt:") && itemData.DataSource.Description == nameof(DataSource.CustomDataTableValue))
        {
            itemData.Content = dtRow[itemData.Content.Replace("cdt:", "")].ToString();
        }
    }

    tableSortOrder++;
    itemDataList.AddRange(tempTable.ToList());
}


private static List<IItemData> CreateCopyOfTemplate(IItemData itemData, List<IItemData> newTable, List<IItemData> templateTable, List<IItemData> originalTable, int? origParentId, int tableSortOrder)
{
    List<IItemData> childList = templateTable.Where(x => x.ParentId == origParentId).ToList();

    if (itemData.DataSource != null && itemData.DataSource.Description == nameof(DataSource.CustomDataTable))
    {
        itemData.Id = originalTable.Max(x => x.Id) + 1;
        itemData.SortOrder = tableSortOrder;
        newTable.Add(itemData);
    }

    foreach (IItemData childItem in childList)
    {
        origParentId = childItem.Id;
        childItem.ParentId = itemData.Id;
        childItem.Id = newTable.Max(x => x.Id) + 1;
        newTable.Add(childItem);

        CreateCopyOfTemplate(childItem, newTable, templateTable, originalTable, origParentId, tableSortOrder);
    }

    return newTable;
}
```

Where on each pass of the ForEach loop I create a new `List<IITemData>` named tempTable. I populate this with a method, a few other bits then Add it to the Range of another List named itemDataList.

I have firstly initiated the tempTable list within the loop and have also used ToList() when applying to the main list however the records added in on the first pass of the loop are all updated with the values of the second pass of the loop - thus ending up with duplicate data in my list!

I get the feeling I am missing something obvious but it has been a long day and just cannot figure it out.

Comment: I don't think you've shown us enough code to determine what the actual problem is.    Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have updated with my full code... Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like you are reusing the "item" object in each pass of the foreach loop, you make some changes to it in CreateCopyOfTemplate, and then add it to newTable and return it. Only to pass it in again, make some changes and return it. Ultimately using the same reference

```
if (itemData.DataSource != null && itemData.DataSource.Description == nameof(DataSource.CustomDataTable))
{

    itemData.Id = originalTable.Max(x => x.Id) + 1;
    itemData.SortOrder = tableSortOrder;
    newTable.Add(itemData); <-- Here you keep adding the same item
}
```

You could instantiate a new instance of an object implementing IItemData and use that instead. An easy way might be to deep copy the object there or just manually set all the properties.

Look here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I foolishly thought that by doing ToList() would create a fresh instance not referenced to the original tempTable list... Is this not the case? If not then how do I apply the tempTable list without a reference?

Comment: It does, but somewhere in the code (I imagine in MethodToReturnListItems) it is causing it to use references instead.

Comment: Ahh okies, I am still learning some of these finer points and didnt know that was a thing. I will update with the full code... I hoped the above little snippet would e enough but obviously not.

Comment: So I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like you are reusing the "item" object in each pass of the foreach loop, you make some changes to it in CreateCopyOfTemplate, and then add i to newTable and return it. Only to pass it in again, make some changes and return it. Ultimately using the same reference

Comment: I think I need to scrub up on my References... I thought I should still be able to like 'Clone' the tempTable before it is added to the itemDataList but that doesnt seem to be the case. Could you suggest anything to get around this? The functionality itself has bent my brain!

Comment: Well I don't know where you are referencing that "item" object from. But instead of updating it and adding it to newTable each time in CreateCopyOfTemplate, you could instantiate a new instance of IItemData there and add that to newTable instead.

Comment: If this solved your problem, would you please mark it as the answer?

Comment: Done and thank you. Got me right back on the right path!